# PHP - convert code section from a string to html characters

Tags: php, html, string

I have string like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> link </a>
[code lang="html" anotherargument="foo"...]
<a href="http://google.com"> link </a>
[/code]
```

How can I convert the code wrapped between `[code...]` and `[/code]` to HTML characters?

like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> link </a>
[code lang="html" anotherargument="foo"...]
&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt; link &lt;/a&gt;
[/code]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match_all('`\[code[^\]]*+]([^\[]*+)\[/code\]`i', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $html = str_replace($match[1], htmlentities($match[1]), $html);
}
```

Comment: thank you. do you know how can I do the same for `<pre lang="html"> ... </pre>` ?

Comment: change the pattern string to `|<pre[^>]*+>([^<]*+)</pre>|i`

Answer (score 1):

I think [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) have the functionality you are looking for. Both convert characters to HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions with a callback - so match the what is between code tags, then replace by running through a function.

Something like this untested code:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\[code.+?\])(.+?)(\[\/code\])/', create_function(
            '$m',
            'return $m[1] . htmlentities($m[2]) . $m[3];'
        ),$str)
```

Comment: i think you mean [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)